# How to divide a variable with the number of inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable s and i want to divide that variable with the number of inputs there are. I am a beginner, can anyone tell me the code that can perform that action?

I haven't tried anything because i don't know the specific code that can perform that action.

```
x = int(input("Insert x: "))
y = int(input("Insert y: "))

s = x + y


print(s/number of inputs)
```

I expect the output of s/number of inputs.

Comment: You have two inputs in your code sample only so, `print(s/2)`

Comment: What do you mean by "number of inputs"? Do you want to calculate the average of a set of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is needed but you can define your own function that inputs and increments a global counter:

```
number_of_inputs = 0

def my_input(msg):
    global number_of_inputs
    x = input(msg)
    number_of_inputs += 1
    return x

x = int(my_input("Insert x: "))
y = int(my_input("Insert y: "))

s = x + y

print(s / number_of_inputs)
```

Input:

```
Insert x: 10
Insert y: 20
```

Output:

```
15.0
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me with my problem, I was hoping that there is a code that can be fit in only one line per example declare a variable that can count the inputs but it is good as it is, thank you!